# Is there any method or query by which we can capture resource usage for running query in MySQL server

Tags: mysql, database, memory-management, cpu-usage

any query / method by which we can capture the resource usage for running query or stored procedure? Can anyone help me with this please !?

Answer (score 0):

There are some queries that you can use to help you monitor this, such as:

View Running Queries:

`mysql> SHOW PROCESSLIST;`

View the MySQL server status variables which will give you statistical performance data:

`mysql> SHOW SERVER STATUS;`

Also, you can show an engine's status:

`mysql> SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;`

Comment: Thanksss,Can you give me idea that how to optimize  the stored procedure so that we can optimize cpu_resource-usage  in my database or is there any method for that how to do this?

Comment: Not getting anything from it .. can you more alloborate please.

Comment: Are you getting an error? Also, I cannot give you any suggestions on optimizing your stored procedure without seeing it, you could post it as another question, perhaps on the dba stack exchange: https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: So first I need to get cpu usage for particular stored procedures so is it possible or any method there  to get cpu usage for particular stored procedure or query ?